# Need help on a Whitelist Key System

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make it were people will need to get a key, then they have to type the key into a TextBox, then click a done button and if its right I want it to take them to a different form.

The issue is that I want it to be where if the key is anything else but the right key it displays a mbox saying incorrect key and stays on the same form, but every time I try to do something like that it just takes me to the next form and still says incorrect key.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "Aim4last") ;
    Main temp = new Main();
    temp.Region = this.Region;
    temp.Show();
    this.Hide();

    if (textBox1.Text == "") ;
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Key");
}
```

Comment: Note that the `visual-studio` tag is intended for questions pertaining to the Visual Studio application itself, and not code you write with it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your code is how you define your `if` statements:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "") ;
```

The `;` at the end signifies that the code to be executed if the condition is `true` is now complete. I'm not sure this compiles, but if it does, you essentially have a NO-OP.

If statements can be written in two ways:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("abc");
    // you can place as much code inside the block as you like, and it will only be executed if the condition is true
}
```

In this style, the `if` statement will execute the enclosed block (`{ ... }`) below it. Alternatively, you can write the `if` statement like this:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "")
    MessageBox.Show("abc"); // this can be on the same line as the if statement.
    MessageBox.Show("def"); // this line is not part of the if statement and will always execute regardless of the condition being met
```

In this style, the `if` statement executes a single line of code when the condition is met. Note that the `def` MessageBox is not part of the `if` statement, so it will always be executed.

So, we should write your code like this:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "Aim4last")
{
    Main temp = new Main();
    temp.Region = this.Region;
    temp.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
else if (textBox1.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Key");
}
```

This leads to a new problem: we only have two conditions, `"Aim4last"` or `""`. The textbox can contain other values, but won't result in a messagebox when the key is wrong. To fix this, change it to an `else` instead of an `else if`:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "Aim4last")
{
    Main temp = new Main();
    temp.Region = this.Region;
    temp.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Key");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else

You're not putting your logic into code blocks. Basically your if statements are doing nothing and the code is continuing to process every line.

```
if (textBox1.Text == "Aim4last")
{
    Main temp = new Main();
    temp.Region = this.Region;
    temp.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
else if (textBox1.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Key");
}
```

What that doesn't handle is key that's neither blank, nor the one you want. You probably just want to do an else:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "Aim4last")
{
    Main temp = new Main();
    temp.Region = this.Region;
    temp.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Key");
}
```